# mysqldump --compatible=oracle gives error

Tags: mysql

From

[mysqldump option name '--compatible' as documented in mysql developer site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible)

We have -

> - --compatible
>
> Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or with older MySQL servers. The value of name can be ansi, mysql323, mysql40, postgresql, oracle, mssql, db2, maxdb, no_key_options, no_table_options, or no_field_options. To use several values, separate them by commas. These values have the same meaning as the corresponding options for setting the server SQL mode. See Section 5.1.10, “Server SQL Modes”.
>
> This option does not guarantee compatibility with other servers. It only enables those SQL mode values that are currently available for making dump output more compatible. For example, --compatible=oracle does not map data types to Oracle types or use Oracle comment syntax.

Here, I have a query -

```
mysqldump -u admin -p  database1 --compatible=oracle > /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/test.sql
Invalid mode to --compatible: oracle
```

Why am I getting this error?

Update:

Only `ansi` mode is not giving `invalid mode` error, but it is giving a separate error -

```
mysqldump -u admin -p  database3 --compatible=ansi > /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/test.sql
Enter password: 
mysqldump: Error: 'Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'information_schema.FILES.EXTRA' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by' when trying to dump tablespaces
```

Even after turning off `only_full_group_by` the error persists -

```
SET sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

The rest all the options gives `invalid mode` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing a link to the documentation for the very old MySQL 5.6.  The documentation for the current MySQL 8 says the only allowed value now is `ansi`.  If ansi format is not good enough for you, you could install the mariadb client tools (which I believe can connect to a MySQL 8 server) and use mariadb-dump which still has the oracle option (but note that it does not actually produce oracle data types or comment syntax).